# Hover styles for child not working using mui styled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using mui styled in my project for styling and I have a card element and on its hover i want a backdrop to appear on the card but the styles are not being applied on hover. I want ImgHoverBackdrop to get these styles on hover of ImgContainer  `display:'block', background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',` but they are not applying. How can i achieve this?

```
const ImgContainer=styled(Box)({
  width:'100%',
  height:'80%',
  position:'relative',
  '&:hover ': {
    display:'block',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
  },
})

const ImgHoverBackdrop=styled(Box)({
  display:'none',
  width:'100%',
  height:'100%',
  top:'0',
  right:'0',
  position:'absolute',
  background:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  transition: 'background 0.3s',
}, { name: 'img-hover-backdrop' })


const ComponentGrid = () => {

  return (
    <ContainerGrid>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {paginatedArray.length===0 ? 
          (<Grid xs={12} sx={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', height:'40rem'}} item>
            <MessagePara>No items to show</MessagePara>
            </Grid>)
          : (paginatedArray.map((product,index)=>{
              return <Grid xs={12} sm={6} md={3} sx={{height:'20rem', cursor:'pointer'}} item key={index}>
                  <ImgContainer>
                    <img style={{ width:'100%',height:'100%', objectFit:'cover'}} src={product.img_url}/>
                    <ImgHoverBackdrop>
                    fssdfdfdsf
                    </ImgHoverBackdrop>
                  </ImgContainer>
                 <HeadingsContainer>
                  <h5>{product.category_type}</h5>
                  <h5>{product.product_type}</h5>
                  <h5>${product.price}</h5>
                 </HeadingsContainer>                
              </Grid>
          }))}  
      </Grid>
    </ContainerGrid>
  )
}
```